# Passing back an array of custom objects from C#.NET DLL to MFC

Tags: c#, com

Here is an example XML data file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AssignmentHistory Version="171804">
    <W20160104>
        <StudentItems>
            <Item>
                <Name Counsel="13" NextCounsel="0" Completed="1">Name 1</Name>
                <Type>Bible Reading (Main)</Type>
            </Item>
        </StudentItems>
    </W20160104>
    <W20160111>
        <StudentItems>
            <Item>
                <Name Counsel="9" NextCounsel="9" Completed="0">Name 2</Name>
                <Type>Bible Reading (Main)</Type>
            </Item>
            <Item Description="Initial Call">
                <Name Counsel="37" NextCounsel="38" Completed="1">Name 1</Name>
                <Type>#1 Student (Main)</Type>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Name>Name 3</Name>
                <Type>Assistant</Type>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Name Counsel="48" NextCounsel="49" Completed="1">Name 4</Name>
                <Type>#2 Student (Main)</Type>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Name>Name 5</Name>
                <Type>Assistant</Type>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Name Counsel="27" NextCounsel="30" Completed="1">Name 6</Name>
                <Type>#3 Student (Main)</Type>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Name>Name 7</Name>
                <Type>Assistant</Type>
            </Item>
        </StudentItems>
    </W20160111>
</AssignmentHistory>
```

I have written some code that reads the XML data file and locates future assignment history for a given name. For example, if the week is 4 Jan 2016, and we are getting the history for Name 1, then my code will return a list of entries (in this case, just 1, for the week on 11 Jan 2016).

My code:

My method is behaving fine:

```
public void ExtractFutureStudentHistory(String strStudent, DateTime datWeekOfMeeting, String strHistoryDatabase, out DateTime[] aryFutureDates, out string[] aryFutureAssignTypes, out int[] aryFutureStudyNo)
{
    XmlDocument docAssignHistory = new XmlDocument();

    aryFutureDates = null;
    aryFutureAssignTypes = null;
    aryFutureStudyNo = null;

    List<DateTime> listFutureDates = new List<DateTime>();
    List<string> listFutureAssignTypes = new List<string>();
    List<int> listFutureStudyNo = new List<int>();

    try
    {
        docAssignHistory.Load(strHistoryDatabase);

        // The data in the XML should already be in ascending date order

        // The data we want:

        // AssignmentHistory/<WYYYYMMDD>/StudentItems/Item/Name
        // AssignmentHistory/<WYYYYMMDD>/StudentItems/Item/Type
        XmlNodeList listHistory = docAssignHistory.SelectNodes("AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item[Name='" + strStudent + "']");
        foreach(XmlNode nodeHistoryItem in listHistory)
        {
            XmlNode weekNode = nodeHistoryItem.ParentNode.ParentNode;
            String strWeekDate = weekNode.Name.Substring(1); // This skips the preceding "W"

            DateTime dateHistoryItemWeekOfMeeting = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(strWeekDate.Substring(0, 4)),
                                    Convert.ToInt32(strWeekDate.Substring(4, 2)),
                                    Convert.ToInt32(strWeekDate.Substring(6, 2)));

            if (dateHistoryItemWeekOfMeeting.Date > datWeekOfMeeting.Date)
            {
                // We need to include it
                listFutureDates.Add(dateHistoryItemWeekOfMeeting);
                listFutureStudyNo.Add(Convert.ToInt32(nodeHistoryItem.SelectSingleNode("Name").Attributes["Counsel"].Value));
                listFutureAssignTypes.Add(nodeHistoryItem.SelectSingleNode("Type").InnerText);
            }
        }

        aryFutureDates = listFutureDates.ToArray();
        aryFutureStudyNo = listFutureStudyNo.ToArray();
        aryFutureAssignTypes = listFutureAssignTypes.ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SimpleLog.Log(ex);
    }
}
```

Possibly the logic can be simplified, but it works. My issue comes with the fact that my method is part of a C# .NET DLL. At the moment then I have this public interface method:

```
[Guid("xx")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IMSAToolsLibraryInterface
{
    void ExtractFutureStudentHistory(String strStudent, DateTime datWeekOfMeeting, String strHistoryDatabase, out DateTime[] aryFutureDates, out string[] aryFutureAssignTypes, out Int32[] aryFutureStudyNo);

 }
```

It works fine. In C++ MFC I have three `SAFEARRAY**` objects, one of type `BSTR`, one of type `DATE` and one of type `int`. No problem with that it itself.

My question is, can my function be changed to output a single list of objects? For example, if I created a class:

`StudentItem` that had three member variables for the date, assignment type and study number.

I tried changing my function parameter to `out List<StudentItem>` but that didn't work. Then I changed it to `out StudentItem[]` and I still couldn't work with it.

I declared `StudentItem` as a basic `struct` with three members. What is the right way to declare this object so I can pass it back as an array for working with in MFC?

Thanks.

## Update

Step 1:

I added a new object to the DLL project:

```
[Guid("xx")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public struct StudentItem
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime Week { get; set; }
    public int Study { get; set; }
}
```

Step 2:

I add a reference in the interface:

```
void ExtractFutureStudentHistory2(String strStudent, DateTime datWeekOfMeeting, String strHistoryDatabase, out StudentItem[] aryStudentItems);
```

Step 3:

I add the adjusted method:

```
public void ExtractFutureStudentHistory2(String strStudent, DateTime datWeekOfMeeting, String strHistoryDatabase, out StudentItem[] aryStudentItems)
{
    XmlDocument docAssignHistory = new XmlDocument();

    aryStudentItems = null;

    List<StudentItem> listStudentItems = new List<StudentItem>();

    try
    {
        docAssignHistory.Load(strHistoryDatabase);

        // The data in the XML should already be in ascending date order

        // The data we want:

        // AssignmentHistory/<WYYYYMMDD>/StudentItems/Item/Name
        // AssignmentHistory/<WYYYYMMDD>/StudentItems/Item/Type
        XmlNodeList listHistory = docAssignHistory.SelectNodes("AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item[Name='" + strStudent + "']");
        foreach (XmlNode nodeHistoryItem in listHistory)
        {
            XmlNode weekNode = nodeHistoryItem.ParentNode.ParentNode;
            String strWeekDate = weekNode.Name.Substring(1); // This skips the preceding "W"

            DateTime dateHistoryItemWeekOfMeeting = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(strWeekDate.Substring(0, 4)),
                                    Convert.ToInt32(strWeekDate.Substring(4, 2)),
                                    Convert.ToInt32(strWeekDate.Substring(6, 2)));

            if (dateHistoryItemWeekOfMeeting.Date > datWeekOfMeeting.Date)
            {
                StudentItem oItem = new StudentItem();
                oItem.Week = dateHistoryItemWeekOfMeeting;
                oItem.Type = nodeHistoryItem.SelectSingleNode("Type").InnerText;
                oItem.Study = Convert.ToInt32(nodeHistoryItem.SelectSingleNode("Name").Attributes["Counsel"].Value);

                listStudentItems.Add(oItem);
            }
        }

        aryStudentItems = listStudentItems.ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SimpleLog.Log(ex);
    }
}
```

Step 4:

I compile the DLL. I get a problem:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4556,5):
> warning : Type library exporter warning processing
> 'MSAToolsLibrary.StudentItem.k__BackingField, MSAToolsLibrary'.
> Warning: The public struct contains one or more non-public fields that
> will be exported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here:

Remove the auto-implemented properties. This exposes your struct in a well-known fashion, which can be used by COM clients:

```
[Guid("xx")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct StudentItem
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string Type;
    public DateTime Week;
    public int Study;
}
```

... or use an interface. Properties are fully supported in COM interfaces:

```
[Guid("xx")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface StudentItem
{
    string Type { get; set; }
    DateTime Week { get; set; }
    int Study { get; set; }
}
```

As a side note, you might consider changing your method as follows:

```
StudentItem[] ExtractFutureStudentHistory2(String strStudent, DateTime datWeekOfMeeting, String strHistoryDatabase);
```

This makes it easier to use the method in your client, since the array is now declared as a standard return parameter.

Comment: Thank you. Out of the two choices you provide would there be a preference?

Comment: I'd recommend the interface approach, since it's easier to use. With a struct, you'll need to use the `IRecordInfo` interface to gain access to its layout.

Answer (score -2):

You can return a structure Assignment like in code below.  I used xml linq to parse entire xml into a list.  You can query the list object

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication73
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<Assignment> assignments = doc.Root.Elements().Select(x => new
            {
                items = x.Descendants("Item").Select(y => new Assignment()
                {
                    date = DateTime.ParseExact(x.Name.LocalName.Substring(1),"yyyyMMdd",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    _type = (string)y.Descendants("Type").FirstOrDefault(),
                    name = (string)y.Descendants("Name").FirstOrDefault(),
                    counsel = (string)y.Descendants("Name").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("Counsel"),
                    nextCounsil = (string)y.Descendants("Name").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("NextCounsel"),
                    completed = y.Descendants("Name").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("Completed") == null ? false :
                       ((int)y.Descendants("Name").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("Completed")) == 0 ? false : true
                }).ToList()
            }).SelectMany(x => x.items).ToList();
        }
    }
    public struct Assignment
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public string counsel { get; set; }
        public string nextCounsil { get; set; }
        public Boolean completed { get; set; }
        public string _type { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not taking into account the C# application is a DLL that I call from C++ MFC ...

Comment: So what?  As long as the structure is defined the same in c++ you can pass the structure start address (pointer) in unmanaged memory just like with a c language application.  All you are doing by passing a pointer is pushing the start address of the object onto the call stack.

Comment: The error says something isn't public.  Everything looks public except : public static void ExtractFutureStudentHistory2(String strStudent, DateTime datWeekOfMeeting, String strHistoryDatabase, out StudentItem[] aryStudentItems);

Comment: David is making comments again that are not accurate.  Ignore is comments.

Comment: The function is publicly defined. I think I am missing required com interface steps so that I) it compiles correctly and ii) the objects are properly exposed so that I not only can get them as an array but that I can use them efficiently from the MFC side of things.

Comment: @jdweng This question concerns COM interop between a C++ MFC program and a C# class library, exposed via COM using `ComVisible`. You showed a console program that presented a different way to parse the XML (not a problem for the asker) but ignored the interop which is the entire point of the question. You really ought to listen to both me and the asker who are telling you that you have not appreciated what the question is about.